# SSH tunneling to remote server with docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to write a Dockerfile to access a remote mySQL database using ssh tunneling.

Tried with the following `Run` command:

```
ssh   -f -N username@hostname -L [local port]:[database host]:[remote port] StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

and getting this error:

> "Host key verification failed" ERROR

Comment: Did the answer help? If yes, please accept the answer. If not, please provide feedback and/or more information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Docker container does not have access to any SSH data (i.e.: there is no `~/.ssh/known_hosts`), you have two ways to handle this:

1. Use `ssh-keyscan -t rsa server.example.com > ~/.ssh/my_known_hosts` from within the container to add the remote host
2. Or copy the relevant line from an existing `my_known_hosts` or simply `COPY` a the whole file to the container.

Either of these approaches should do it.